# Smooth scrolling nor working when element is dynamically wrapped with anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive, smooth-scrolling

For the mobile devices I want to convert all the `h1` headings to anchors that can scroll smoothly to their target. To achieve that, when a certain device resize occurs, i just wrap the content of the `h1` tag with an `a` tag and then unwrap the content of the `a` tag when the device comes back to desktop width.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Add smooth scrolling to all links
  $("a").on('click', function(event) {

    // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
    if (this.hash !== "") {
      // Prevent default anchor click behavior
      event.preventDefault();

      // Store hash
      var hash = this.hash;

      // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
      // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
      }, 800, function() {

        // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
        window.location.hash = hash;
      });
    } // End if
  });
});


//the function to convert the heading to an anchor for devices smaller than 780px
function makeResponsive() {
  if ($(window).width() < 780) {
    if ($('a').length) {
      return true;
    } else {
      $('h1').each(function() {
        $(this).contents().eq(0).wrap('<a href="#section2"></a>');
      });
    }


  } else {
    $('a').contents().unwrap();
  }
}

//run on document load and on window resize
$(document).ready(function() {

  //on load
  makeResponsive()

  //on resize
  $(window).resize(function() {
    makeResponsive();
  });

});
```

```css
body,
html,
.main {
  height: 100%;
}

section {
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>
  The Heading
</h1>

<div class="main">
  <section></section>
</div>

<div class="main" id="section2">
  <section style="background-color:blue"></section>
</div>
```

The problem is that when the h1 content is converted to an anchor, the smooth scrolling is not happening at all and the anchor just jumps to the target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your a-Tag doesn´t get the click event, because you add the listener when it doesn´t exist.

Try this

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(event) {...
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of wrapping it in anchors, just add 'mobile-anchor' class to those headings. Then, instead of listening for clicks on anchor, listen for clicks on 'mobile-anchor' and change:

```
$('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#section2').offset().top
}, 800, function() {
```

Or even a simpler solution - before the very end of your on click function, add a 'return false;' so the browser doesn't scroll the page down by itself.

EDIT: Also, wrap everything in a single documentReady function and execute the makeResponsive() before adding a click listener.